# Cannot set a cookie before redirection

Tags: iphone, session, mobile, cookies, webkit

We have a weird problem in that I have developed a mobile version of our website that just sits in a sub folder of the site e.g /mobile/page.asp (I know .asp classic don't blame me!)

I did want to create two domains one for the mobile site one for the normal site but I was told by our CTO to just do a sub folder.

However the problem is we want to be able to set a cookie that lets us know whether the user WANTS to be on the main site OR mobile site. They could in theory be on a desktop and still choose to go the mobile version (as we have links in the footer to switch views, e.g from the main site to the mobile site and vice versa).

However if someone comes to the site without a cookie set we do some user-agent sniffing do determine their device and then set a cookie before redirecting them to the right part of the site.

All our logic seemed correct however when we started testing it we started getting weird results.

On my iPhone 3gs it was working perfectly (most up to date OS) however on other peoples iPhones or Android phones people would
-clear cookies (at the beginning of the test)
-visit the site 
-the agent sniff would redirect them to the mobile site
-but when they clicked on a further link on the mobile site the code took them back to the full site.

This didn't happen for me - also on our demo site it worked for some people and not for others - and also for someone on an Android device who downloaded FireFox it worked fine.

I and another developer who had the problem sat together and went through the steps one by one, doing the exact same thing, with debug on showing us what was going on.

However whilst I was getting a cookie set to "mobile" when I went to the mobile site he for some reason wasn't. It was like the cookie couldn't be set before a redirect even though the redirect was to the same domain.

I read some articles which said there was some issue in webkit with cookies and redirects which made me think this could be the issue on the iPhone Safari browser but that wouldn't explain why my 3Gs phone worked.

We have tried re-working the code but we need to be able to set cookies and do redirects in all cases. We even tried just changing the code that was setting a cookie to a session variable but even that didn't work.

I am really stuck and so is everyone else. We have spend days trying to debug it but cannot find a common denominator which would explain why it works on some devices but not others.

Can anyone help!!! Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Cripes.  I'm about to ask the exact same question - right down to redirecting to a full site from a mobile site. And there's no answer here.  Doesn't look good.  If I get a good answer, I'll come back here and add a link to it.